# Get First Name from logged user - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm a beginner in WordPress and PHP and I need your help and advice.
I'm using Contact Form 7, and in my .php file I want to add some code that will get the First Name of the user that is logged, and automatically write it into the First Name field in the Contact Form.
I'm trying this code, but it's not working. (fname is the id I've given to the field First Name in the Contact Form)

```
<?php
    global $priv;
    $priv = $current_user->user_firstname;
?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#fname').val("<?php echo $priv; ?>");
    });
</script>
```

What am I missing? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();   
?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#fname').val('<?php echo esc_js( $current_user->user_firstname ); ?>');
    });
</script>
```